# How to mock an http.get in angular2

Tags: angular

Let me explain.

I have this kind of request in "matiere.service.ts"

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class MatiereService {
   private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/tpFormation-web';

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   list() {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/matiere`);
   }

   find(id) {
       return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/matiere/${id}`);
   }
}
```

I would like to have something like a fakematiere.service.ts that is creating fake request. I'll lit to do it because the REST api I am connecting to is not coded yet. I have checked around "in-memory-web-api" but I don't know if it's the right tool and tho, I don't really know how to implement it.

Any help?

Comment: `in memeory api ` is the one that will be help ful in the case, or you might even consider having a dummy json file in your assets and load it while doing a http call

Comment: If you don't want to Stub it or Mock it then use something like this: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. `npm install -g json-server`

Answer (score 1):

As per what @Rahul said, if you are only doing gets, a json file is quick and easy.

I have an example of using a json file here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted

Basically, you just need to change this line of code:

```
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/tpFormation-web';
```

To point to your json file.

But if you have put/post/etc, then in memory api is the way to go.

I have an example of using in memory api here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Answer (score 0):

I did use

`npm install -g json-server`

Work perfectly!

Thanks